# Json decode into php

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to decode API to PHP.

API EXM

```
{
"users":[
          {"user":"john",
          "user1":"Tabby",
          "user2":"Ruby",
          "user3":"Silver"}
]
}
```

tilte users = 0 (It's empty)

I tried with this code but it's not working (blank page)

```
<?php
$json = '{ "users"[ {"user":"john", "user1":"Tabby", "user2":"Ruby", "user3":"Silver"}';

$arr = json_decode($json);

echo $arr->users->{0}->user; //blank page
echo $arr->users->user1; //blank page
echo $arr->users->0->user2; //syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
?>
```

Comment: Your json in the program in invalid. Your missing `]}` $arr is null.

Comment: And after fixing that, consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php).

Comment: I believe because the website working with java ("oracle" mentioned in URL). this code just a little example for the real code (full page)..

Comment: Try using the `[0]` syntax to get to that user `$arr->users[0]->user`

Comment: Yes users[0] Worked Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$arr->users` is an array and not an object. So if you change your script to

```
<?php
$json = '{
"users":[
    {"user":"john",
    "user1":"Tabby",
    "user2":"Ruby",
    "user3":"Silver"}
]
}';

$arr = json_decode($json);
print_r($arr);

echo $arr->users[0]->user,"\n";
echo $arr->users[0]->user1,"\n";
echo $arr->users[0]->user2,"\n";
?>
```

... the output is ...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user] => john
                    [user1] => Tabby
                    [user2] => Ruby
                    [user3] => Silver
                )

        )

)
john
Tabby
Ruby
```

Comment: What if looks like this ?   



{"address":[{
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska",
    "AS": "American Samoa",
    "AZ": "Arizona",
    "AR": "Arkansas",
    "details":{
    "1":{
    "total":{
    "id1":"140.0",
    "id2":"140.0"
}}}
    }]}


PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @stackr: My PHP decodes your json sting very well (without error).

Comment: yes it's working with first example but its not working with this one ( more levels),  {"address":[{ "AL": "Alabama", "AK": "Alaska", "AS": "American Samoa", "AZ": "Arizona", "AR": "Arkansas", "details":{ "1":{ "total":{ "id1":"140.0", "id2":"140.0" }}}}]}

Comment: I have no issues with the second string. I did: `$j = ' ... '; $a = json_decode($j); print_r($a);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $json = '{
  "users":[
      {"user":"john",
      "user1":"Tabby",
      "user2":"Ruby",
      "user3":"Silver"}
   ]
 }';
$json = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$json);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($arr);
?>
```